# With Handsontable, how to give a fixed width while enabling AutoColumnSize?

Tags: handsontable

I am attempting to create a spreadsheet where there's a minimal width for each column, but setting both `colWidths` and `autoColumnResize` in the settings seem to negate the auto column resizing.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(container,{
        data: data,
        colWidths:100,
        autoColumnResize:true  // negated by the colWidths setting
  });
```

If I remove the colWidths setting, the column resizes fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the following object in the option autoColumnResize :

```
autoColumnResize:{syncLimit: 100},
```

The columns widths will be resize dynamically but with a minimum value of 100. See [this quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/zsska5ru/).

You can find in [the documentation](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/Options.html#autoColumnSize) the difference between the use of syncLimit and asyncLimit :

> Column width calculations are divided into sync and async part. Each
>   of this part has own advantages and disadvantages. Synchronous
>   counting is faster but it blocks browser UI and asynchronous is slower
>   but it does not block Browser UI.